# The following Javascript for loading

Tags: jquery

```
//Taken from jQl:
var jQl = {
    "q": [],
    "unq": function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < jQl.q.length; i++)
        jQl.q[i]();
        jQl.q = [];
    },
    "ready": function(f, t) {
        if (typeof f == 'function') {
            if (typeof t != undefined && t == true) {
                jQl.q.unshift(f);
            } else {
                jQl.q.push(f);
            }
        }
        // return jQl in order to support jQuery(document).ready()
        return jQl;
    },

    "bId": null,
    "boot": function(callback) {
        if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined' || typeof window.jQuery.fn == 'undefined') {
            if (!jQl.bId) {
                jQl.bId = setInterval(function() {
                    jQl.boot(callback)
                }, 25);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (jQl.bId) {
            clearInterval(jQl.bId);
        }
        jQl.bId = 0;
        // OK, jQuery is loaded,
        // we can load additional jQuery dependents modules
        //jQl.unqjQdep();
        // then unqueue all inline calls
        // (when document is ready)
        $(jQl.unq());

        // call the callback if provided
        if (typeof callback == 'function') callback();
    }
}​
```

jQuery Loader is an async nonblocking loader for jquery and jquery plugins. The benefit of Loader is to loading jQuery and dependent plugins simultaneously, without affecting rendering on the page.

1. jQl, jQuery loader, `q` stands for `queue`, and initially `q` is an empty array `[]`. `unq` stands for `unqueue`, which loops through the jQuery queue and dequeues to download.
2. When it's ready, if `f` is a function, the jQuery queue `unshift`s. *I don't know what `unshift` does?* Versus `push` for the jQuery Loader queue.
3. *I am not too clear on `bID` thing?* In the `setInterval` function.

Comment: @j08691 - Somehow yes. I tried to highlight what I thought they were.

Comment: This should probably be split up into multiple questions, all reduced to relevant code only. Dumping everything you have and listing what doubts came through your head is not a good way to get answers.

Comment: Also, the line of code "jQl.unqjQdep();" just gave me cancer. I'd drop a library using method names that dumb.

Comment: JQL is a query language for a [modestly popular issue tracking system](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching). Sounds sorta like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), um, light..

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what unshift does?

`unshift` is an array method. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4].unshift()
```

returns 4

> I am not too clear on bID thing?

```
`bID` is the boot ID, a variable initially set to `null`, then set to `0` when jQuery loads
```